# diagrammatic question(2)

Tags: pattern

[image: question]

I promise it is not from a contest. From my friend. But answer is not provided and I wanna know. Just like a IQ question

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling. I have strong intuition that you are with the new user, as you've edited that [question](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/38824/1766) too. Please make sure this is not from an ongoing contest, and [provide the source of the puzzle](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/a-policy-on-plagiarism?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: @2012rcampion what comes next, I presume :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd choose

> A

because

> the outer shape in position N becomes the inner shape in N+2: outer hexagon in 1 and inner hexagon in 3, diagonal square in 2 and 4 and hexagon in 3 and 5. So the next figure should have a normal square in the middle, and A is the only one.

I could get it wrong, but right now I don't see other solutions.